# How to create command with -register and <reg>?

Tags: vimscript

I have never used [:h :command-register](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Acommand-register) and [:h <reg>](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Creg%3E) , trying to find an example, but failed to grep `\-register` from my installed plugins,

The built in `:h :delete` support a count and an optional register:

```
:[range]d[elete] [x] {count}
            Delete {count} lines, starting with [range]
            (default: current line |cmdline-ranges|) [into
            register x].
```

How to create similar command?

**Failed Attempt**

```
function s:delete(reg, count) abort
  let reg = empty(a:reg) ? '"' : a:reg
  exe 'delete' reg a:count
endfunction
command -nargs=1 -register Delete call s:delete('<reg>', <f-args>)
```

Test:

```
Delete 3
---------
E471: Argument required: Delete 3

Delete 30
---------
Error detected while processing function <SNR>100_delete:
line    2:
E488: Trailing characters: delete 3 0

Delete a 3
----------
works fine
```

It doesn't look like optional at all, it looks like it always use 1st char or 1st arg as register.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with `-reg` is that anything that looks like a register is parsed as such, even when there's no separator to the following arguments. So `:Delete 30` sets `<reg>` to `3` (numbered register) and `0` as the argument. Unfortunately, `:delete` itself seems to use different parsing rules; it doesn't accept a numbered register, so instead of getting `E939: Positive count required` you see `E488`.

Because of these problems, I tend to skip `-reg` and do the parsing on my own (using [ingo#cmdargs#register#ParsePrependedWritableRegister()](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-ingo-library/blob/74cd607baa3436409bbad4fd2caa19ff1e0502e3/autoload/ingo/cmdargs/register.vim#L57-L80) from my [ingo-library plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433)), enforcing whitespace separation between the register and further arguments. That may explain why you haven't found any plugins using `-reg`.

To make `:Delete 3` work, you either have to use custom parsing that does not treat `3` as a register, or make the arguments optional via `-nargs=?`.

Comment: Should it be `E488`  in the end of 1st paragraph? I'm not sure i completely follow, I guess i need some time to digest it.

Comment: Yes `E488`; corrected.